# Docker build image complain about: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile, clone

I am using this Dockerfile content:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git /cloned-qt    
RUN cd /cloned-qt/   
RUN git checkout 5.11
RUN git pull
```

Once I run my build image command:

```
sudo docker build -t qt5.11-auto:v1 .
```

I get this error message:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/10 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> ea4c82dcd15a
Step 2/10 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 60e7c61ea78c
Step 3/10 : RUN apt-get install git -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 50a4def0607e
Step 4/10 : RUN git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git /cloned-qt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 97fb8ab6dc15
Step 5/10 : RUN cd /cloned-qt/
 ---> Running in 9be03fba40fa
Removing intermediate container 9be03fba40fa
 ---> 130bc457eb66
Step 6/10 : RUN git checkout 5.11
 ---> Running in 35de823fdf9c
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

After this failed step, when I run the container and execute the same commands I manage to run them successfully.
what seems to be the reason that the docker build fail to run the "git checkout" command but when running it inside the container it works?

Comment: Maybe build the container up to step 5 and then try the next steps in an interactive shell?

Comment: Did it and it is working from the shell... I don't understand why from the shell it is working and from the dockerfile build not. maybe it is related to user permissions or to folder access?

Comment: What about using `WORKDIR` instead of `cd`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change the "RUN cd /cloned-qt/" command to "WORKDIR cloned-qt"
and it will work as expected

Comment: I thought this would be the case.

Answer (score 6):

Each time you do a `RUN`, docker creates a new temporary container to run it therefore command like cd has no effect.

Do

`WORKDIR /cloned-qt/`

instead of

`RUN cd /cloned-qt/`

Answer (score 1):

merge step 5 and 6 into single layer like below.

RUN cd /cloned-qt/ && git checkout 5.11